# Python running multiple processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a script (**a.py**) that needs to call another script (**b.py**) multiple times, each execution of **b.py** takes 1 minute. If I run in a for loop, this takes a lot of time.

I want to know how I can optimize this, to reduce the time. 
Any help or suggestions would be very helpful.

Source code:

```
# a.py
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
    script_path = 'b.py'

    # Some logging statements. 
    for infile in inputs:
    os.system("{} -i {}".format(script_path, infile))  


# b.py
    # take arguments
    # perform some operations
    # log the execution
```

So far, I have been using `os.system` to call the other script. How can I call the script **b.py** n times in parallel ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your post to show what you have tried. All of the generous programmers on stackoverflow are much more helpful if you provide something as a base for us to work with. The least you can do is provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: have a look at the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `muliprocessing.Process` to run it in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

inputs = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
script_path = 'b.py'

def run(script, name):
    os.system("{} -i {}".format(script, name))  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']
    script_path = 'b.py'
    for infile in inputs:
        p = Process(target=run, args=(script_path, infile))
        p.start()
    p.join()
```

**Note**: Executing a Python script from a Python script with `os.system` is not very elegant. You should modify your script `b.py` that it works as a module which provides its main functionality with functions or classes as well. Then you can import `b` and use these functions or classes instead.

Comment: Subprocess looks good, I haven't used this module before. I will give it a go. 
Also, even if I make it a module and import the functions, it still works serially, right ? How can I invoke it in parallel.

Comment: The parallel execution is done by `subprocess`. Of course, my suggestion is to execute the code of module `b` in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way you can optimise this as such. If you want to run script b for each item in a list, then iteration is the only way to do this. It might be that you can alter the contents of script b to run faster, but that is a different problem.